# pgmm and pvargmm producing different results in GMM estimations

Tags: r, panel-data, plm, gmm

I'm trying to estimate a GMM model. I tried both the **pgmm** function from the **plm** package and the **pvargmm** function from the **panelvar** package. For some reason, the two packages do not generate the same results for the following regression model. I do not have the same problem when I do not introduce any non-linear terms in my specification (e.g., quits_rate.emp_rate.L). I'm quite confused about which package I should rely on and what's causing this difference? Any help would be much appreciated.

```
DC3 <- pgmm(investment_rate ~    
              lag(investment_rate) + 
              profit_rate.L + quits_rate.L
            + quits_rate.emp_rate.L | lag(investment_rate, 2:4)  + 
              lag(profit_rate.L, 1:4) + 
              lag(quits_rate.L, 1:4)+ 
              lag(quits_rate.emp_rate.L, 1:4)
            , effect = "twoways" , index=c("state", "year"), 
            data=pgmmm_df, collapse = T, robust=TRUE,
            transformation="d", model = "twosteps")
```

```
DC3.v2 <- pvargmm(
  dependent_vars = c("investment_rate"),
  lags = 1,
  predet_vars=c("profit_rate.L",
                "quits_rate.L",
                "quits_rate.emp_rate.L"
                ), 
  exog_vars=c("yr2003","yr2004","yr2005","yr2006"
              ,"yr2007", "yr2008", "yr2009","yr2010", "yr2011", "yr2012",
              "yr2013", "yr2014", "yr2015","yr2016", "yr2017", "yr2018", "yr2019"),
  transformation = "fd",
  data = pgmmm_df,
  panel_identifier = c("state", "year"),
  steps = c("twostep"),
  system_instruments = FALSE,
  max_instr_dependent_vars = 4,
  max_instr_predet_vars = 4,
  collapse = TRUE
)
```